# Website-like navigation in Xamarin mobile application

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, navigation

I am going to develop an application for iOS and Android with Xamarin, that has to contain **some posts, with the possibility to embed a link to another post (within the app) right into the content**. Content should be loaded from some server.

The new **Eurosport app can be a very good example** of what I am talking about. Many of their news contain links to other news right inside their text, and when you tap one, you see an app's loadscreen, and then the new post shows up.

The deal is, I am almost new to Xamarin (and mobile app development in general), so I got a bit lost, and the more I google, the less I understand. **Is it actually possible to achive this with Xamarin (dosen't really matter, Forms or separate platfroms), and what kind of solution it can possibly be?** Maybe some frameworks like Prism, or anything else, Deep Links also seem to be sth that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. The way I believe many apps do it is their links are actually links to their website. These links redirect the user to open the equivalent page on the app through a process called [Deep Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/deep-linking).

I can't possibly explain it better than the aforementioned article, so click on it and have a read.